# How to resolve “RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED” with status code: 8 on Google cloud disk insert method

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am making api request to create disks to the Google Cloud platform and get status code as 200.so but when i check if disk is ready i get that "error":{"code":404 ,"reason":"notFound","domain":"global"}. when i check google cloud logs i see for request the below error code. "status": { "code": 8, "message": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED" } -can anyone help possible solutions for this like which exact quota limit should be increased? i have tried retry mechanism with pause included abt 3 sec's with that i was able to reduce the probability but the real issue still there.

Comment: Edit your question with more context. What size, how often and in which region?

Comment: Your question is incomplete and is missing information. In order to increase the chances of getting an answer, I suggest you read this post (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about  how to ask good questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can request for an increase in the quota allocation using the GCP Console -> IAM & Admin -> Quotas. Please find the Compute Engine Quota that is showing up as exceeded and click on it to drill down to the specific operation types. I believe you were hitting the limit "Operation read requests"

you may have hit an operation read request [limit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits).